# Scanf Specific Error Condition on Character Input

Tags: c

I'm having trouble reporting a specific error case when using scanf for my program.

I need to support having an input of a decimal number, followed by a single character,

```
scanf("%lf %c", &number, &units);
```

However, this will work for the case if someone enters `42Hello`, and `units` will be `H`, and `scanf` will return `2`.

I however am looking for an elegant solution to catch the ability to enter more than 1 character.

I've thought about accepting a string instead of a character and counting the length of the string, but I wonder if there's a better way to capture this error condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> an elegant solution to catch the ability to enter more than 1 character.

Read the *line* of user input with `fgets()`

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
  Handle_EOF_or_Error();
} else {
```

Then parse `buf` with `sscanf()` with appended `" %n"` to the format to record where scanning stopped - if scanning reached the end.

```
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(buf "%lf %c %n", &number, &units, &n);
  if (n == 0 || buf[n]) {
    Handle_Bad_Input(buf);
  } else
    // Now use `number` and `units`
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution for you:

```
scanf("%ld %c%c", &number, &units, &newline);
if (newline != '\n') {
    /* ERROR */
}
```

So essentially, you force the user to press enter after their input. Does that fit your needs?

Comment: You also have to check the return value of `scanf` here

Comment: Consider what happens with input `"123\n"`.  `scanf("%ld %c%c"` will wait for input of the next _line_ as in `"123\nH\n"`.  Perhaps that case is acceptable or not to OP.

Answer (score 0):

A reasonably elegant solution is to require the user to append some specified character at the end of his/her input:

```
printf("Enter input followed by period: ");
scanf("%lf %c %c", &number, &units, &period);
```

And just check that the second character is indeed a period. I realize this only works if units is too be only one character long.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to have exact inputs or else this would work perfectly.